# Android getChildFragmentManager inside -> viewpager -> viewpager -> fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I have structure viewpager(B) -> viewpager(A) /on one page/-> fragment.

When i open viewpager(B) first time, i see all that i need. When i select some pages on viewpager(A) and after that try to open page with viewpager(B) i cant see anymore pages inside it.

Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getChildFragmentManager());
static class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {...}
...

AdapterB adapter = new AdapterB(getChildFragmentManager());
static class AdapterB extends FragmentPagerAdapter {...}

Thanks for u help ;)

Comment: it's not good design to put one viewPager inside another one, i think you need think more about UX

Comment: You should use onResume() method.

Comment: Have you tried using `getFragmentManager()`?

Comment: getFragmentManager() not working for chilld fragments.

Comment: onResume() for what?